# Select records of previous month and show 0 if no records are there in specific time-window

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I have this query to get a list of drives that occurred for a specific month in a time window of 1 year back.

```
SELECT COUNT( drives.id ) AS drives, DATE_FORMAT( drives.timestamp,  '%d-%m-%Y' ) AS mdate
FROM drives, users
WHERE drives.user = '146'
AND DATE_FORMAT( drives.timestamp,  '%b' ) =  'Feb'
AND drives.timestamp > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH) 
GROUP BY DATE(drives.timestamp) ORDER BY drives.timestamp ASC
```

I get the following result:

```
drives  mdate
1       14-02-2013
2       17-02-2013
```

However I would like a result with every date of the month even if no records are found for that date, and display 0 next to the date that no drives took place.The tricky part for me is how to get the exact dates of the specific month in 1 year back timewindow.
I could implement this with php but I would prefer a cleaner solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559817/sql-query-that-returns-all-dates-not-used-in-a-table

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where the users table comes into this (you are cross joining it, but not actually using it anywhere), but something like this should do what you require (not tested).

```
SELECT Sub1.aDay, COUNT( drives.id ) AS drives
FROM
(
    SELECT DATE_ADD('2013-02-01', INTERVAL units.i + tens.i * 10 DAY) AS aDay
    FROM
    (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) units
    CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) tens
    HAVING MONTH(aDay) = 2
) Sub1
LEFT OUTER JOIN drives
ON Sub1.aDay = DATE(drives.timestamp)
WHERE drives.user = '146'
GROUP BY DATE(drives.timestamp) 
ORDER BY drives.timestamp ASC
```