# MySQL - Get missing entries in a date range

Tags: mysql, date, range

I have a table with the following structure:

```
Entry ID | Date | Approved
```

Whenever a new entry is made, Entry ID auto increments and date is set to whenever the entry was made through the web application. These entries are not necessarily made every day, so there are gaps between dates.

I need to find all "missing" entries, meaning that there is no entry for that date. For instance, if there was an entry for 2015-06-01 and the next one didn't come until 2015-06-07, I need a query that returns the list of dates from 2015-06-02 to 2015-06-06 and an indication of their approved status from that field. I've been looking for a while but can't seem to find a method to get a list of entries that don't exist. Is there a method for this, or should I restructure?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL query that returns all dates not used in a table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559817/sql-query-that-returns-all-dates-not-used-in-a-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a temp table with all possible dates and do

```
SELECT Date FROM temp_table WHERE Date NOT IN (SELECT Date FROM your_table);
```