# How to return zero values if nothing was written in time interval?

Tags: mysql, sql, gaps-and-islands

I am using the Graph Reports for the select below. The MySQL database only has the active records in the database, so if no records are in the database from X hours till Y hours that select does not return anything. So in my case, I need that select return Paypal zero values as well even the no activity was in the database. And I do not understand how to use the `UNION` function or re-create select in order to get the zero values if nothing was recorded in the database in time interval. Could you please help?

```
select STR_TO_DATE ( DATE_FORMAT(`acctstarttime`,'%y-%m-%d %H'),'%y-%m-%d %H') 
as '#date', count(*) as `Active Paid Accounts`  
from radacct_history where `paymentmethod` = 'PayPal' 
group by DATE_FORMAT(`#date`,'%y-%m-%d %H')
```

When I run the select the output is:

[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMYbB.jpg)

But I need if there are no values between 2016-07-27 07:00:00 and 2016-07-28 11:00:00, then in every hour it should show zero active accounts Like that:

[Needed output with no values every hour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEvMI.jpg)

I have created such select below , but it not put to every hour the zero value like i need. showing the big gap between the 12 Sep and 13 Sep anyway, but there should be the zero values every hour

(select STR_TO_DATE ( DATE_FORMAT(`acctstarttime`,'%y-%m-%d %H'),'%y-%m-%d %H') 
as '#date', count(paymentmethod) as `Active Paid Accounts`
from radacct_history where `paymentmethod` <> 'PayPal' 
group by DATE_FORMAT(`#date`,'%y-%m-%d %H'))
union ALL
(select STR_TO_DATE ( DATE_FORMAT(`acctstarttime`,'%y-%m-%d %H'),'%y-%m-%d %H') 
as '#date',  0 as `Active Paid Accounts`
from radacct_history where `paymentmethod` <> 'PayPal' 
group by DATE_FORMAT(`#date`,'%y-%m-%d %H')) ;

Comment: Sample data and desired output will be very helpful to get the appropriate answer soon.

Comment: I have uploaded outputs in my answer . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you want to return 0 if there is no matching rows in MySQL. Here is an example:

```
(SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3 FROM ExampleTable WHERE ID='1234')
 UNION (SELECT 'Def Val' AS Col1,'none' AS Col2,'' AS Col3) LIMIT 1;
```

**Updated the post:** You are trying to retrieve data that aren't present in the table, I guess in reference to the output provided. So in this case, you have to maintain a date table to show the date that aren't in the table. Please refer to this and it's little bit tricky - [SQL query that returns all dates not used in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559817/sql-query-that-returns-all-dates-not-used-in-a-table)

Comment: Thanks, but that sample returns no zeros

Comment: Please check the link I provided. I hope, it will help you to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You need an artificial table with all necessary time intervals. E.g. if you need daily data create a table and add all day dates e.g. start from 1970 till 2100.

Then you can use the table and LEFT JOIN your radacct_history. So for each desired interval you will have group item (group by should be based on the intervals table.